# SharePoint Online modern site: Create Site column with multilingual Title using powershell

Tags: powershell, column, online, multilingual, modern

I can't figure-out how to create a site column with multilingual Title in SharePoint Online on modern sites using powershell.
Example: I would like to create a column with the English Title "columnEn" and then for the French UI I would like to update the Title to "columnFR". So, English users with english UI will see columnEN and French users with french UI will see columnFR.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full script handy, but here is the gist:

$c.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture($l, "Title for that language")

$c is the column, $l is the locale.

Comment: Than you for your reply. It didn't work. I'm trying to add French translation to the column. I tried both 1036 and "fr-FR".

Comment: I also tried $c.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

Comment: The following code worked for me:
            $c.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("fr-FR", "Title fpr the language")
            $c.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
            $c.Update()
            Invoke-PnPQuery

Comment: Just found-out that column translation didn't carried over to the list. Please help.

Comment: Not certain what you mean, didn't carry over?  Are you referring to site column? What is being translated and what isn't?

Comment: Here is what mean: The default language in SharePoint online is English. I create site column, then in French UI I update the Title of this column. After that I add this column to the content type and then add this content type to the document library. 
After that I update the French Title of the site column using Powershell. When I verify the update, I see that the site column Title was update, but when I check the document library I see that column still has the old Title.

Comment: Unfortunately, the inheritance of translations of content types & site columns is not great.  You have to provide the translations to the site columns before adding them to a list/library, otherwise they don't automatically inherit them.  You can still change the translation of the list-specific instance of the column if it was added before the change.  Similarly for inheriting from content type hubs.  Changes to the translations are not propagated.

Comment: Thank you Martin!. I'll have to keep in mind that any updates to site columns will not be propagated to their instances. More maintenance :(